# How to run custom django-admin commands as a cron job in docker?

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, cron

I have a django-app `sample`. In this app I have created a file `test.py` and wrote my custom commands in it as mentioned in the [django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)

```
sample/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            test.py
    views.py
```

**test.py:**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Sample content
        print("Hello World")
```

I had run the command `python manage.py test` and it is working. What I need is that I want to run this command as a cron job in docker. I had tried this, created a cron file `hello-cron`.

**hello-cron:**

```
* * * * * root python /home/manage.py test >> /home/cron.log 2>&1

# Empty line
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.10.6
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /home
COPY requirements.txt /home/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /home/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
COPY hello-cron /home/hello-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /home/hello-cron
RUN chmod 0744 /home/sample/management/commands/test.py
RUN crontab /home/hello-cron
RUN touch /home/cron.log
CMD cron && tail -f /home/cron.log
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/home
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I had run the container by using the command `docker-compose up --build`, but cron job is not working. How can I run custom django-admin commands as a cron job in docker?

Comment: The Compose file you show overrides `command:` to run the Django Web server, rather than the `tail` command.  You also may have problems where the `volumes:` overwrite the `RUN chmod ...` Dockerfile commands.  Does deleting these lines help your setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze No, it is not working